# How to run .hta file from within .html file w/o asking to download it

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I want to run .hta file from within .html file w/o the browser asking to download it.It should run in an iframe in the html page in the browser. The code i am using is this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="app.hta">
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the browser asks to download the hta file but it want that it should run automatically.

The hta file code is this-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
        BORDER="no"
        CAPTION="no"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        SYSMENU="yes"
        SCROLL="no"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/app.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your server configured to correctly provide the right MIME type for an `.hta` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't open a [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) within `iframe` even if the main app was a HTA. HTAs have their own OS windows, just like a browser or any .exe has.

What you can do, is to put your script to a regular html file. Depending on the security settings of IE, it executes the code, or ask user to allow to execute, or throws an error.

Notice also, that `ActiveX`s work only in Internet Explorer. And like Dark Falcon has said, allowing `ActiveX` execution from web would be a huge security risk. So trying to do these kind of things at a public website is not recommended.

If this is an intranet app, you can change the main app to HTA. Then you can add `Run Notepad` button (and the script) to the main app, or to an `iframe`, which has `application=yes` set. Also trusted sites (html) can run `ActiveX`s without prompting or errors.

Answer (score 0):

HTAs cannot be run under the browser. They run under a special host process called `mshta`. Allowing opening of an HTA in a browser frame would be asking for problems, as HTAs have much higher privileges than normal web pages.

Comment: Then how can i open an exe file from a webpage?

Comment: You can't. This would be a huge security hole. Why couldn't some page just open a virus on your machine?

Comment: But if the app is already on the user's machine? Such as simply launching notepad.exe from a webpage w/o the need to download anything on the user's machine.